# Recycler View: Item Position is wrong for Nexus 5

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

Item Position always taken as 0 inside onBindViewHolder and hence i am only getting one list item in recycler view although I have passed huge list in adapter.

This issue is occurring in some devices including Nexus 5 while my recycler view is working fine for few other devices like s5.

Can any body tell me what may be going wrong?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Please post your adapter code

Answer (score 0):

From what you described, please check the code in your `getItemCount()` implementation. This method manages how many items you see and from your description it returns 1 for some reason.

Comment: My getItemCount is returning 6, but in onBindViewHolder I am always getting position as 0

Comment: How does it return the value? I am 100% sure that the problem is there. Try to hard code some value like 10 and it should show more items.

Answer (score 0):

The issue came after I upgraded my support libraries from 23.2.1 to 23.3.0. After I downgraded my design and recycler-view support library to 23.2.1 version, my issue got resolved.

Some change in latest support library is causing this issue. Could not find the solution while using latest support libaries